# Programmatically adding a label to objective-c ios app does not show

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to add a Label UI programmatically into my objective-c view controller, but after coding it nothing shows, below is my code:

`

```
   //
    //  ViewController.m
    //  ObjectiveWebView
    //

    #import "ViewController.h"

    @interface ViewController ()


    @end

    @implementation ViewController


    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        UILabel *yourLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 70)];
        [yourLabel setTextColor:[UIColor brownColor]];
        [yourLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [yourLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Trebuchet MS" size: 14.0f]];
        [self.view addSubview:yourLabel];
    }

    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
        NSLog(@"viewDidAppear loaded successfully");
    }

    @end
```

`

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe it's not showing because there are no text? Try adding text or changing the background color from clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text for the label is never set. By default, it is empty. So in your case, the label is getting added to the view but not visible as the text is not set. Try setting it. Also, if the ViewController is embedded in NavigationController, the label might have been hidden under the navigation bar. Try changing the y position of the label as below.

```
        UILabel *yourLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 300, 70)];
        [yourLabel setTextColor:[UIColor brownColor]];
        [yourLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [yourLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Trebuchet MS" size: 14.0f]];
        [yourLabel setText:@"Hello"];
        [self.view addSubview:yourLabel];
```